# How can I add number of orders in array?

Tags: python

How can I add number of orders in array?

I get result data from this Python command.

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT animal FROM myapp_animal ORDER BY idx DESC LIMIT 3")
results = cursor.fetchall()
x = cursor.description
resultsList = []   
for r in results:
    i = 0
    d = {}
    while i < len(x):
        d[x[i][0]] = r[i]
        i = i+1
    resultsList.append(d)

return HttpResponse(resultsList)
```

Here is the data of result array:

```
'result' : [{'animal' : 'cat' }, {'animal' : 'dog' }, {'animal' : 'horse' }]
```

I would like to make it like this:

```
'result' : [{'order' : '0' , 'animal' : 'cat' }, {'order':'1', 'animal' : 'dog' }, {'order' : '2', 'animal' : 'horse' }]
```

What should I do to add number of orders in array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others explain your mistake but why don't use `enumerate` ?

```
>>> res = [{'animal': 'cat' }, {'animal': 'dog' }, {'animal': 'horse' }]
>>> for i, j in enumerate(res):
...      j.update({'order': i})
... 
>>> res
[{'order': 0, 'animal': 'cat'}, {'order': 1, 'animal': 'dog'}, {'order': 2, 'animal': 'horse'}]
```

Comment: why are you using update to create a key/value pairing?

Comment: I think `j["order"] = i` is pretty readable and the idiomatic way to add a key/value to a dict

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
d = {}
```

use:

```
d = { order: i }
```

Or if you really want the value of the `order` to be a string, use:

```
d = { order: str(i) }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a structure like dict, but with ordering, maybe you should pay attention to the OrderedDict:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: It is not a usecase for OrderedList, because of this line: `return HttpResponse(resultsList)`

Comment: @sobolevn All Lists are ordered.  Don't you mean OrderedDict?

Comment: @kubus Rather than giving a link, perhaps you could provide an example of how it could be used in this case to solve the OP's question.

Comment: @Alexander, yes, OrderedDict.